# $f(\alpha _I) \ne 0$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, self-learning

I need help in this question...

Let $F$ be a field of *characteristic zero* and let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space over field $F$. If $\alpha _1,\dots , \alpha_m$ are finitely many vectors in $V$ , prove that there is a linear functional $f$ on $V$ such that
$$f(\alpha _i ) \ne 0 \space \forall \space i\in 1,\dots , m .$$

I will be very grateful if someone gives step by step solution to the above problem.. Thanks in advance.

I have two more specific doubts..

$1)$ What is meant by *characteristic zero*?

$2)$ Can I define $m$ linear functionals $f_1, \dots ,f_m$ in the following way (inspite of the fact that $\alpha _1,\dots , \alpha_m$ need not be a basis.) 
$$f_i (\alpha _j)=\delta _{i,j}$$ where $\delta_{i,j}$ is the Kronecker delta function ?

Please help me if I am wrong...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $\alpha_{1},\ldots,\alpha_{m}$ are vectors different from zero vector, then there is a linear functional $f$ such that $f(\alpha_{i})\neq 0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/127447/if-alpha-1-ldots-alpha-m-are-vectors-different-from-zero-vector-then-t)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Characteristic zero means that if you take the multiplicative identity element $\mathbf 1 $ of the field, there is no $n$ such that $\sum_{i=1}^n \mathbf 1 = 0$, i.e. you can't sum it a finite times to end up with the additive identity element. As pointed out in the comments, the fields usually used in linear algebra, namely $\mathbb R, \mathbb C, \mathbb Q$ have characteristic zero. An example of a field with doesn't have characteristic zero is the field consisting of two elements $\{0,1\}$ where $1 + 1 = 0$.

2)Yes, you can do this, as long as you assume additionally that $\alpha_j \neq 0$ for all $j$ and take care of the fact that linear dependence can cause headaches.

Let $\beta_1 \dots \beta_{k}$ be a basis of $\operatorname{span}\{\alpha_1, \dots \alpha_m\}$. An alternative way to define the (same) $f_j$ would be:

$f_j(\alpha) = \begin{cases}\mu & \mbox{if } \alpha = \mu\beta_j \mbox{ for some } \mu \in F\\0 & \mbox{otherwise}.\end{cases}$.

These are indeed linear functionals. Hence, also $$f = \sum_{i=1}^k f_i$$

is a linear functional. We have for $\alpha = \sum_{j=1}^k \mu_j\beta_j:$

$$f(\alpha) = \sum_{j=1}^k \mu_j f_j(\beta_j)=\sum_{j=1}^k \mu_j.$$

Why is this sum $\neq 0$ for $\alpha = \alpha_j$? Is the characteristic $0$ important here?

What's $f(0)$ for any functional?

What would happen if we hadn't done the step with beta? How would $f$ look like in the case for $\alpha_1 = -\alpha_2$ (and $n=2$)?

Comment: A remark on the first point: $\mathbb{R},\mathbb{Q}$, and $\mathbb{C}$ all have characteristic zero. A simple (and somewhat pathological) example of a field which doesn't have characteristic zero is the field with two elements, which has $1+1=0$.

Comment: @Ian : That was an extremely helpful remark... It's worth the up vote..

Comment: @Qwerty: My bad. I have to admit that I'm more used to linear algebra where the field is $\mathbb R$ or $\mathbb C$. Since you were posing the question in this generality, I assumed that this rather abstract approach is in the spirit of the question. Apparently not. I've included the remark in my answer.

Comment: @Roland : No no...I am a beginner, and I am quite as used to $\mathbb R or \mathbb C$ as you. In fact I have not even been exposed to working with other fields... I just got Ian's remark interesting, that's why I thanked him.. Your answer is prefect for me.